# how to count number unique values in each column, R, efficiently

Tags: r, unique

my goal is to look for how many unique values each column in my data frame has, here is what I came up with

```
### df is a data frame, 32 named columns, millions of rows 

test1 <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))

### I get a named integer from the above command 

test2 <- data.frame(names(test1), test1)

### now I get a data frame, with row names

row.names(test2) <- NULL

### to get rid of the row names 

test3 <- test2[order(test1),]

### finally I get a what I want
```

my question would be, how do I do this in a smaller number of steps???

Comment: Try `library(data.table); library(reshape2);unique(setDT(melt(as.matrix(df))[-1]))[, .N, Var2][order(N)]`

Comment: can you (1) give a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) (hint: it doesn't have to be huge); (2) explain *why* you want to do it in fewer steps?  Do you want better efficiency (which seems unlikely)? Cleaner code (you could wrap this in a function if you have to do it frequently ...)?  Are you just presenting a challenge/trying to deepen your R knowledge?

Comment: @akrun If using packages, it seem's like data.table's `uniqueN` and the dplyr analogue would be the way to go.

Comment: start running your benchmarks in 3 ... 2 ... 1 ...

Comment: @Frank Some days ago, I got a comment that `uniqueN` is not as fast as `length(unique(`.

Comment: @akrun Oh, interesting. If you want to, I bet the devs would appreciate a demonstration of that posted as an issue on github.

Comment: @Frank I think it was DavidArenburg who showed a link in github or so.. Don't remember much.

Comment: before we start benchmarking: how long does what you've got posted above actually take to run on your data ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One call in base R:

```
#using the same column names as in your example
test1 <- data.frame(names.test1 = colnames(mtcars), 
                    test1=sapply(mtcars, function(x) length(unique(x))),
                    row.names=NULL)
```

Output:

```
> test1
   names.test1 test1
1          mpg    25
2          cyl     3
3         disp    27
4           hp    22
5         drat    22
6           wt    29
7         qsec    30
8           vs     2
9           am     2
10        gear     3
11        carb     6
```

This would then require manual ordering though as @BenBolker mentions in the comment:

```
test1 <- test1[order(test1$test1),])
```

However, you could do an ordered one-liner with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
test1 <- data.table(names.test1 = colnames(mtcars), 
                    test1=sapply(mtcars, function(x) length(unique(x))),
                    key='test1')

> test1
    names.test1 test1
 1:          vs     2
 2:          am     2
 3:         cyl     3
 4:        gear     3
 5:        carb     6
 6:          hp    22
 7:        drat    22
 8:         mpg    25
 9:        disp    27
10:          wt    29
11:        qsec    30
```

Comment: this doesn't sort the data frame as the OP wants.   Could add that to a one-liner with `[d]plyr::arrange`, but you might need one more line (`test1[order(test1$test1),]`) in base R ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BenBolker. You are right. I was looking for a way for an one-liner and the only thing I came up with was to use `data.table`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you want. 
Please provide a sample of your dataset (with `dput`)

Imagine you want to count the number of unique values for the data `mtcars`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise( ndist = n_distinct(value) ) %>% 
  arrange(desc(ndist))
```

This will give you

```
    key ndist
1  qsec    30
2    wt    29
3  disp    27
4   mpg    25
5    hp    22
6  drat    22
7  carb     6
8   cyl     3
9  gear     3
10   vs     2
11   am     2
```

Comment: how about making that `...  summarize(nvals=n_distinct(value)) %>% arrange(nvals)` to sort it as the OP requests ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this doing what you mean?

```
    test1 <- sort(sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))), decreasing = T)
    data.frame(names(test1), test1, row.names = NULL)
```